# AJAX calls return results in a (seemingly) synchronous manner

Tags: php, ajax, apache, yii

All,

### Background of how problem was detected

My question concerns the performance of a web app, mainly the index page. I noticed the problem when I was giving a demonstration at a local branch of my company that has slow internet (I don't know the exact speeds, or ping rate) judged by the fact that Google took about 10 seconds to load. My index page took ~10-20 times longer to load. I was under the assumption that my app did most of the work on the server side (as php is making all of the database queries...). But this led me to look at the network tool of Chrome and see the latency times of these 4 divs being loaded by ajax (I'll elaborate in a bit). Interestingly, the scripts being called appear to run sequentially, but not necessarily in the order I invoked the ajax calls (sometimes they do, other times they don't).

### What are these divs / ajax requests?

Here is a code snippets of a request:

```
    Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('leftDiv', '
    $( "#left_dash" ).load(
        "'.$this->createUrl("/site/page?view=leftDashLoad") .'", 
         function(){ 
            $("#left_dash p a").click(function() {
                $(this).parent().parent().find("div.scroll100").slideUp();
                $(this).parent().next().stop(false, false).slideDown();
            });

            $("p:first-child").next().slideDown();
        }
     );
 ' );
```

Here is the page requested:

```
$this->widget('widgets.ScrollList',array(
    'condition'=> 
        function($muddJob,$scrollList) 
        {
              $job = $muddJob->Job;; //returns a job or empty array
              if(!empty($job) )
              {
                 if( $muddJob->uploadArtwork == null && $muddJob->uploadData == null  ) {
                     array_push($scrollList->_models,$job);
                     $scrollList->columnValues = array($muddJob->jobDescription,$muddJob->dropDate1);
                     return true;
                 }

              }

              return false;

        },
     'columns' => array('col1'=>"MuddJob#",'col2'=>"Desc",'col3'=>"Dealer Name"),
     'name'=> "Print New Ticket",
     'muddJobs' => $currentExchanges->getCurrentMuddExchanges(),

        )
    );
```

Imagine that page (the page that ajax has called) having 6 similar declarations that create widgets. The goal is to return html to put back in place of a loading gif on the index page.

Here is the scroll widget:

```
<?php
Yii::import('widgets.ScrollListBase');
include_once Yii::app()->extensionPath . "/BusinessDay.php"; 

class ScrollList extends ScrollListBase
{
    private $_content;
    public $columns = array();
    public $columnValues;
    private  $_listInfo;
    public $name;
    public $_models = array();
    public $condition; 
    public $muddJobs; //object to pass
    public $jobsMailingTodayArray = array();


public function init()
    {
        //$this->init();
        $this->_listInfo = $this->generateListInfo($this->columns);
        //$muddJobs = $this->getCurrentMuddExchanges(); 
        $listInfo = $this->newScrollList($this->muddJobs);
        $contents = $this->createContent($listInfo,$this->name);
        $this->_content = $contents[0];
//        $this->_fullTableContent = $contents[1];
        //$this->_listInfo = $contents[2];
    }

   public function run()
   {
       //if($this->data['isVisible']) 
       echo $this->_content;
       Yii::app()->session["exploded_content_{$this->name}"] = $this->_models;
   }
    private function newScrollList($muddJobs)
        {
                $listInfo = $this->_listInfo;
                $tempCount = 0;


                foreach($muddJobs as $muddJob) 
                    {

                        $condition = $this->condition;

                        if($condition($muddJob,$this) && empty($this->jobsMailingTodayArray) ) //if no job exists for the muddExchange...
                        {
                            $tempArray = $this->createWidgetLinks($tempCount,$listInfo,$muddJob,$this->columnValues);
                            $listInfo = $tempArray[0];
                            $tempCount = $tempArray[1];

                        }

                        elseif ( !empty($this->jobsMailingTodayArray ) )
                        {
                            foreach ($this->jobsMailingTodayArray as $jobMailingToday)     //change to for loop over the length of the jobsMailingToday
                            {
                                $tempArray = $this->createWidgetLinks($tempCount,$listInfo,$muddJob,$this->columnValues);
                                $listInfo = $tempArray[0];
                                $tempCount = $tempArray[1];
                            }
                            $this->jobsMailingTodayArray = array();
                        }

                    }

                return array($listInfo,$tempCount);


        }

    }
?>
```

Here is it's parent:

```
<?php


class ScrollListBase extends CWidget
{       

        private $content = "<p>";
        private $divDeclaration = "<div class='scroll100'>\n<table class='quickInfoTable'>\n<thead>\n";
        private $headTag = "<th>";
        private $headTagClose = "</th>\n";
        private $theadTagClose = "</thead>\n";
        private $bodyTag = "<tbody>\n";
        private $listInfo = "<div class='scroll100'>\n<table class='quickInfoTable'>\n<thead>\n<th>Job#</th>\n<th>Package#</th>\n<th>Entry Date</th>\n</thead>\n<tbody>\n";


        /**
     * Initializes the widget.
     */

        public function createContent($listInfo,$name)
        {

                $largeHref = Yii::app()->request->baseUrl . '/index.php/site/fullTableView';

                $this->content .= "<span class='badge' >{$listInfo[1]}  </span> <a href='#'>{$name} </a> <a href='$largeHref/Name/{$name}'> <small>(view larger)</small> </a> </p>";


                if( $listInfo[1] > 0 ) 
                {
//                    $this->fullTable .= substr($listInfo[0],22);            
//                    $this->fullTableContent= $this->fullContent .= $this->fullTable . "</tbody>\n</table>\n</div>";

                    $this->content .= $listInfo[0] . "</tbody>\n</table>\n</div>";
                }

            return array($this->content);
        }

//Helper Methods

        /**
         * 
         * @param type $attributeArray. send an accociative array
         * @return type = either a job or an empty array
         */
        protected function getJobByAttributes($attributeArray)
        {
            return Jobs::model()->with('MuddExchange')->findByAttributes($attributeArray);

        }


        protected function createWidgetLinks($tempCount,$listInfo,$muddJob,$columnValues,$url="/MuddExchange/")
       {
            $tempCount++;
            $viewIndex = $muddJob->exchange_id;
            $model = $muddJob;
            $job = $muddJob->Job;
            if ( isset($job ))
            {
                $model = $job;
                $url = "/Jobs/";
                $viewIndex = $model->job_id;
            }
            $link = CHtml::link("$model->jobNumber",array("{$url}{$viewIndex}"));
            $listInfo .= "<tr>\n<td>$link</td>\n";

            foreach ($columnValues as $columnValue)
            {
                $listInfo .= "<td>{$columnValue}</td>\n";
            }

            $listInfo .= "</tr>";

            return array($listInfo,$tempCount);
       }



       protected function getListInfo()
       {
           return $this->listInfo;
       }

       /**
        * Takes an array of strings to generate the column names for a particular list.
        * @param array $heads
        * @return string 
        * 
        */
       protected function generateListInfo($heads) 
       {
           //<th>Job#</th>\n<th>Package#</th>\n<th>Entry Date</th>\n</thead>\n<tbody>\n";
           $htmlScrollStart = $this->divDeclaration;

           foreach ($heads as $tableColumn => $name)
           {
               $htmlScrollStart .= $this->headTag . $name . $this->headTagClose;
           }

           $htmlScrollStart .= $this->theadTagClose . $this->bodyTag;

           return $htmlScrollStart;
       }





    public function calculateDueDate($jobsMailDate,$job)
    {
        $package = PackageSchedule::model()->findByAttributes(array('package_id'=>$job->packageID));
        $projectedDays = $package->projected_days_before_mail_date;

        $dropDate1 = $jobsMailDate->projected_mail_date;
        $dropDate = wrapBusinessDay($dropDate1); //use this for actual command...  
        $toSec = 24*60*60;
        $dayInt =0;
        $secDropDate = strtotime($dropDate1);

        do{
           $dayInt +=1; 
           $daysInSec = ($dayInt)  * $toSec ;
           $secGuessDueDate = $secDropDate - $daysInSec; 
           $dueDate = date('Y-m-d',$secGuessDueDate);

           $difference = $dropDate->difference($dueDate);


        }while( $difference != $projectedDays);
        return $dueDate;
    }
}
?>
```

### Why I think this behavior is odd

The whole slow internet thing is a beast in and of itself, but I don't think that is in the scope of StackOverflow. I'm more concerned about the loading of these divs. The div that loads last, i.e., takes on average 1.5 to 2 seconds, is an ajax request to a page that creates a single widget. The logic behind it is here:

```
<?php
 include_once Yii::app()->extensionPath . "/CurrentExchanges.php"; 
 $currentExchanges = Yii::app()->session['currentExchanges'];
 $this->layout = 'barebones';
 $this->widget('widgets.ScrollList',array(
    'condition'=> 
        function($muddJob,$scrollList) 
        {
          if ($muddJob->dropDate1 != null && $muddJob->dropDate1 != '0000-00-00')
            {
                $job = $muddJob->Job;;
                if(!empty($job) && $job->packageID != null) //if job exists for the muddExchange and has a package
                {
                    if($job->uploadArtwork == null )
                    {
                        $jobsMailDate = JobsMailDate::model()->findByAttributes(array("job_id"=>$job->job_id,'sequence_num'=>1));
                        if(!empty($jobsMailDate))
                            {
                               $calculatedDueDate = $scrollList->calculateDueDate($jobsMailDate,$job);                                
                                if (strtotime($calculatedDueDate) <= strtotime(date("Y-m-d")) )
                                {
                                    array_push($scrollList->_models , $job);
                                    $scrollList->columnValues = array($muddJob->jobDescription,$muddJob->dropDate1,$jobsMailDate->projected_mail_date);
                                    return true;
                                }
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        },
     'columns' => array('col1'=>"MuddJob#",'col2'=>"Desc",'col3'=>"Drop Date", 'col4' =>'Projected Drop Date'),
     'name'=> "Artwork Due Today",
     'muddJobs' => $currentExchanges->getCurrentMuddExchanges(),

        )
    );
?>
```

The calculateduedate method makes 2 additional calls to the server.

What I'm failing to understand is why the left div (with the most proccessing to do) is usually the first to return and the artLoad is usually the last to load (by a substantial difference). Here are some times returned by chromes network tool:

```
leftDashLoad:  475ms
rightDashLoad: 593ms
dataLoad:      825ms
artLoad:       1.41s

dataLoad:      453ms
rightDashLoad: 660ms
leftDashLoad:  919ms
artLoad:       1.51s

rightDashLoad: 559ms
leftDashLoad:  1.17s
dataLoad:      1.65s  
artLoad:       2.01s
```

I just can't fathom why the left/right dashloads return so much faster than the artLoad. The code for artLoad and dataLoad are nearly identical save the actual comparison (the one if statement). If this were truly asynchronous, I'd expect the order to be art/dataLoad, rightDashLoad and leftDashLoad based purely on the amounts of computation done in each page. Perhaps the server isn't multithreading, or there is some weird configuration, but if that were the case, I don't see why the effects of the loading would be hit so hard by slow internet.
If I have overlooked something obvious or failed to use google appropriately, I do apologize. Thanks for any help you can offer!

### Language/other tech info

The app was developed using the Yii framework. PHP 5.3. Apache Server. INNODB Tables. Server is hosted in dreamhost.

### Update

I've changed the view page so that the ajax calls are now calling a controller action. It seems to have made the loading times more similar (asynchronous?) on my local dev environment, but really slowed it down on the QA environment (hosted on dreamhost...). Here is screen shot of the local network tools info:

[dev environment](http://grab.by/qAu4)

and the qa site (note, that the databases have about the same amounts of data...)

[qa environment](http://grab.by/qAuS)

Thoughts? It seems to me that my original problem may be solved, as the return times (on my local dev) look more like I expect them to.

Also, my own ignorance as to how NetBeans debugs was playing a part in this synchronous loading thing as xdebug is using a session. I believe this was forcing the ajax calls to wait their turn.

Comment: I have found that PHP can not start another request on the same session till the current request either ends or closes its handle on the session. Something to check.

Comment: 6 ajax calls to create 1 view is rude. I doubt this can perform fast enough and it's huge CPU load. Imagine what will be with your server if frontend will be loaded by many users. So my conclusion - make it all in 1 ajax call. Form JSON in your view with all parameters you need in your actions, in php side form json with returned params for widgets, fields etc. Thats alot of work and alot of js, but it will solve a problem.

Comment: Browser will not open more than 2 connections to one server, so if you are making 6 requests, 4 will need to wait before one of the 2 connection finishes.

Comment: Thanks for the input! Perhaps I've misspoke, or just don't understand.
 @ineersa I thought I was making only 4 ajax calls total. The calls take you to a page. Once there, there are no more ajax calls, only creation of more widgets. I thought I was only making 4 ajax calls total. Am I mistaken?

Comment: @MartinKomara same as ineersa, I'm making 6 requests? Perhaps I really don't understand what I've written, or misspoke... I'll edit my question just in case...

Comment: @Rowan I commented out all code using the same session variable and instantiated the object that I was referencing. That means (I think) that php shouldn't be worrying about requests to the session as that session no longer exists. The same behavior is observed (one by one loading of the divs on the page).

Comment: Experiment to try. Remove all the code in the ajax controller action and then have a look at the network timeline. Maybe even put in a sleep so you can control the exact timing of the action.

Comment: @Rowan Great suggestion sir (assuming Rowan is a male alias...)! As you were typing that, I actually timed my calls to these widgets and most of them return instantaneously (surprising to me...). In any case, I commented out all the code in the ajax called pages and it still takes those pages a considerable amount of time to do there thing. Yii seems to be reloading the entire page on these .load calls... The apps main layout is loaded 4 times.  Thoughts?

Comment: How are you returning the content to the ajax call? Are you using  renderPartial() in your action?

Comment: Currently, I have 4 ajax calls in my view that go to another page ( e.g. "/site/page?view=leftDashLoad"), not a controller action. The view itself is rendered initially through render(), but the content is being returned by .load() I thought. Does it make more sense to create four controller actions and have the ajax calls go there and use renderPartial() at the end of the controller actions?

Comment: If you are using CController.render() this will return your view file wrapped up in your layout. CController.renderPartial() only returns the view file. Something to try. It's quite hard to tell without seeing the code in it's entirety.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Rowan! I believe the problem is cured by getting rid of sessions and making the ajax calls reference an action and have that renderPartial(). Again, many thanks my friend. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Rowan for helping me diagnose this strange behavior. PHP was trying to request a session before the session was closed in hopes to prevent a race hazard.  There were session requests in my code, and there was a session started by my IDE (NetBeans). Removing all references to sessions in the ajax called pages and having ajax call actions that use renderPartial() proved to return the expected behavior (and much better code IMO). Let me know how to properly thank users in terms of StackOverflow (can I up comments, or what is there available? ). Thank you all!